# General Question About WPF Control Behavior and using Invoke

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have been putting off activity on SO because my current reputation is "1337".  :)

This is a question of "why" and not "how".  By default, it seems that WPF does not set focus to the first control in a window when it's opening.  In addition, when a textbox gets focus, by default it does not have it's existing text selected.  So basically when I open a window, I want focus on the first control of the window, and if that control is a textbox, I want it's existing text (if any) to be selected.

I found some tips online to accomplish each of these behaviors, and combined them.  The code below, which I placed in the constructor of my window, is what I came up with:

```
Loaded += (sender, e) =>
          {
              MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
              var textBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;
              if (textBox != null)
              {
                  Action select = textBox.SelectAll;
                  //for some reason this doesn't work without using invoke.
                  Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, select);
              }
          };
```

So, my question.  Why does the above not work without using Dispatcher.Invoke?  Is something built into the behavior of the window (or textbox) cause the selected text to be de-selected post-loading?

Maybe related, maybe not--another example of where I had to use Dispatcher.Invoke to control the behavior of a form:

[WPF Focus In Tab Control Content When New Tab is Created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602979/wpf-focus-in-tab-control-content-when-new-tab-is-created)

Comment: Sorry I had to ruin your 1337, but this was a great question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All WPF controls have thread affinity.  The `Dispatcher` manages the thread that each control was created on (typically this is a single thread for every control in the application, but not necessarily).  Work is queued on this thread and executed in priority order.

Any UI-manipulating code has to be executed on the same thread as the control was created on - the `Dispatcher` thread - and so any method has to invoke back to that thread before it can do anything that would affect the UI (such as selecting text in the `TextBox`).

That said, it's my understanding that the `Loaded` eventhandler would fire on the Dispatcher thread by default, so I'm not entirely sure why you're seeing this behaviour in your specific example!

Answer (score 1):

I should start by mentioning i had no issues making that work w/ out the dispatcher call in .net 4.0 (it may have been fixed in the framework update)- however, what the previous poster mentioned is accurate and has been the pardigm since the dawn of winforms (.DoActions() and .Invoke()). However, in 3.5 the above did work w/ out dispatcher if you use a method defined in the codebehind as the target call in your lambda:

```
  Loaded += (sender, e) =>
  {
   this.SelectText();
  };  

  void SelectText()
  {
   MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
   var textBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;

   if (textBox != null)
   {
    textBox.SelectAll();
   }
  }
```

As to why, I cant really give you the specifics but I've run into similar issues w/ using lambdas to route events on presenters. I want to say its something to do w/ reference or context of the compiled expression- in this case it needs a ref to the containing object in order to know how to delegate the operation (selecting the textbox text on the right thread). I also believe that GC can occasionally clean up resources so deferred execution gets botched (seen it in F#...believed that was the cause of my issue in C# as well).